# -sh: source: not found

Tags: python, freebsd, sh

Что имеем?

- FreeBSD 11.2-RELEASE (GENERIC)
- python37, pip3 версии 10.0.1
- Виртуальное окружение, созданное под рутом при помощи модуля питона. Создавалось командой: python -m venv venv

Под обычным пользователем с группой wheel не получается вызвать команды:

1. source venv/bin/activate | ошибка: -sh: source: not found (под рутом работает)
2. ./venv/bin/activate | ошибка: -sh: ./venv/bin/activate: Permission denied (Вроде как точка является синонимом source)
3. с файлами activate.csh, activate.fish ошибки аналогичны пункту 2
4. **UPD** Смотри ниже, права выдал!

В самом файле activate есть комментарий ( получен при помощи man venv/bin/activate ):

```
This file must be used with 
"source.   bin/activate" *from bash*
you cannot run it directly
```

Вижу несколько путей решения (как это вижу я):

1. Проверить права:

   - выдал 777, но с точкой вывод пустой, префикс [venv] не появляется :^)
   - csh /venv/bin/activate.csh | ошибка: prompt: Undefined variable
2. Разобраться с source (сам вкурить не смог)

Comment: Под рут-пользователем команда source имеется, куда копать?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> This file must be used with "source bin/activate" from bash # you cannot run it directly

скрипт требует запускать его из под шелла bash

```
pkg install bash
bash
$ source venv/bin/activate
```

для запуска из под csh есть скрипт **activate.csh**

Comment: файл .csh запускал из csh, ошибка следующая: prompt: Undefined variable. (если честно, то не знаю, какая переменная не определена, а изучать код - мозг кипит), с bash проморгал, сейчас попробуем, спасибо!